# setValue in a whole form with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I'm building up a user profile that has some addresses, the user can edit them, it's almost finished, but I'm stuck in setting the user edit address in a form.
[image: GIF example]

Just like it shows in the GIF when I click the button no value is set, I'm using react-hook-form to build these forms.

This is the function that execute when I click on the button:

```
const editAddress = (i) => {
    const addressClicked = addressList[i];
    console.log(addressWatch());
    setAddressValue("name", addressClicked);
    setShowForm(true);
  };
```

addressList is an array that is being looped, and then I get the key from the `.map(v,i)` and it returns an object with all the information that should populate the input fields for the user to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in the docs there is a function that is called "reset" that actually does exactly what I wanted, it wipes the current data from the form and it can replace with a new object data.
https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset

The function looks like this now

```
const editAddress = (i) => {
    
    const addressClicked = addressList[i];
    addressReset(addressClicked);
    
    setShowForm(true);
  };
```